# Tiles design not consistent

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

In an ASP.Net application, inside a datalist, some tiles have been created as under:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" class="itemdatalist" runat="server" Width="100%" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onitemcommand="DataList2_ItemCommand" RepeatLayout="Flow">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 producttile">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  
    <center><asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("image")%>' class="img-responsive" /></center>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("company")%>' class="couponlabels"></asp:Label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("c_title")%>' class="couponlabels"></asp:Label>
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("c_desc")%>' class="couponlabels"></asp:Label></b>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row coderow">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <b>Code:</b>
       <a href='<%#Eval("c_link")%>' target="_blank">
        <input name="BtnSelect" class="copymove btn-block btn-info" type="button" value='<%#Eval("c_code")%>' title="Click to Copy Code and Shop" />          
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The height of all tiles have been made equal using the following jquery code:

```
$(window).load(function () 
{
 var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".producttile").map(function () {
                    return $(this).height();
 }).get());
 $('.producttile').height(maxHeight);
});
```

and this resizing woks fine.

Now, to ensure that the Code and its button are shown at the bottom of the tiles, following css has been written:

```
.coderow
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5px;
}
```

The problem arises when I resize the browser window to check results at various device sizes. 
At some window sizes I found that the 'Expiring on' label is shown backwards and is overwritten by the code and its button.

I think it is due to absolute positioning of the code portion but cannot figure out a better alternative.

Kindly tell me the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give .coderow a font-size of 1em and then give the margin-bottom of 2 or 2.5 or 3 em to the column containing c_desc.

I think this should work.
However, to view the effect, for every window resize, you will should refresh the page so that your jquery is fired and tile heights are re-adjusted.

Hope this helps.